# How to continue a URL for a new view with already selected primary key (pk) in Django / Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

From my index view I list the available "clubs" in my database, when a user select a club it re-directs them to the club home page. I have included a player registration page but I have no idea how I can render this page based on what club the user selected previously in the index. So what I would like to do is output the url like so: http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/club_home/3/player_registration/ "3" being the primary key of the selected club.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^club_home/$', views.club_home, name='club_home'),
url(r'^club_home/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.club_home, name='club_home_with_pk'),
url(r'^club_home/player_registration/$', views.RegisterPlayer.as_view(), name='player_register'),
```

views.py:

```
class Index(TemplateView):
template_name = 'index.html'

def get(self, request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    clubs = ClubInfo.objects.all()

    args = {'users': users,
            'clubs': clubs}
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)


def club_home(request, pk=None):
if pk:
    club = ClubInfo.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    user = request.user
else:
    club = ClubInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    user = request.user
args = {'club': club,
        'user': user
        }
return render(request, 'club_home_page.html', args)

class RegisterPlayer(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'player_registration.html'

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = PlayerRegistrationSerializer()
        return Response({'serializer': serializer})

   def post(self, request):
        serializer = PlayerRegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'serializer': serializer})
```

model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ClubInfo(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
club_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
club_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True)
club_address1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
club_address2 = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
club_address3 = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
club_town = models.CharField(max_length=30)
club_county = models.CharField(max_length=30)
club_country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
# slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.club_name


class PlayerRegistration(models.Model):

club_name = models.ForeignKey(ClubInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
dob = models.DateField(max_length=8)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15)
emergency_contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
emergency_contact_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15)
address1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
address2 = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
address3 = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
town = models.CharField(max_length=30)
county = models.CharField(max_length=30)
country = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

serialiser:

```
 class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
 class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')


class PlayerRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = PlayerRegistration
    fields = '__all__'
    labels = {
        'dob': ('D.O.B'),
    }
    widgets = {
        'dob': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
    }
```

Comment: Player Registration Model has "club_name = models.ForeignKey(ClubInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this by creating a session key for the primary key. So when the user selects the club a session is created for this pk and i can then use it throughout the project:

```
# set a session variable
self.request.session['key'] = 'value'

# get a session variable
self.request.session.get('key', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just keep the **club_home** end point url pattern and add `player_registration`, so the view you call (`views.RegisterPlayer`) will receive the **club_home** primary key as a parameter:

```
url(r'^club_home/(?P<pk>\d+)/player_registration/$', views.RegisterPlayer.as_view(), name='player_register')
```

Comment: Hi Hugo, I've tried this but I need to amend the view for RegisterPlayer for this to work. Do you know what I've to add? Thanks Gavin

Comment: @user969792, I'll need you to post the code for your models and serializers to complete my answer.

Comment: Hi Hugo, i've amended the question there to include the serialiser & model. Thanks Gavin

Comment: Hi Hugo, to just explain further. I have multiply club pages, when a user selects one, it will bring them to the club profile page, each club will have a registration/roster/rental/shop page associated to it. I just need to figure out how to only associate these pages with the club the user selected. Hope this is a bit clearer. Thanks Gavin